# Filter PowerBI Measure Based on Column

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I am trying to set up a dashboard  with data that looks similar to this:[image: Sample Data]

As you can guess, all of the 'rate' columns are related. I know to create a graphic that shows the totals for all 'rates' I first need to create a measure that is the sum of these 4 columns. My question is, how do I filter that total, based on the columns in the measure?

For example, if I had a line graph for the 'totals' measure:[image: Totals by date]

Is there any way to create a filter visual that would allow me to see just the AA rates on this graph (that is, only measure the sum of the AA rates) or just the UA rates, etc.? Or is there a way to put all 4 columns on the same graph...[image: All totals by date]

and then create a filter visual so single out one of the values fields?

Comment: Unpivot your data in power query, then measure names will appear in a single column as rows. You will then be able to use this new column as a slicer to filter, which rate to show on the graph.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to create another table with names of the measures that you want to show our hide and have the measures return values only when appropriate item is selected. I would opt for the first approach.